# Audacity's Export Selection: How can I export a file using the Nero AAC Encoder?

Tags: command-line, nero, audacity

I'd like to use the Nero AAC Encoder to create my lossy files.

Here's what is happening:

1. I open a WAV file in Audacity.
2. I select the portion of the audio I need to export and click **export selection**.

So, I'm never creating an intermediate slice. My problem is that I don't understand what to pass as the input file:

[image: nero usage]

Here's a non-working command line I'm using in Audacity. It fails because Nero complains about the missing input file. Notice that the Audacity dialog mentions **standard in**, can I use that?
[image: audacity CLE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nero AAC Encoder 1.5.3.0 or newer is required.

To specify standard in, use a hyphen (`-`). Depending on how data is piped you may also have to use the `-ignorelength` switch.

Your command line should look like this:

```
neroAacEnc.exe -ignorelength -q 0.6 -if - -of %f
```

Comment: Isn't 1.5.1 the final version?

Comment: Thank you! Looks like Nero has been updating the binary, but not changing the filename. I currently have 1.5.4.0, even though the download is NeroAACCodec-1.5.1.zip. By the way, I did have to use `-ignorelength`.